# How to send a javascript array to PHP using Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery

How to send a javascript array to PHP using Jquery Ajax.(Note: i will get a Jsondata as a response of the PHP).Also how to get the array variable in php.

**In Javascript:**

```
var userarray=values.toString().split(',');
    var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "http://someURL/server/test.php",
          data:userarray,
          dataType:"json", 
              async: false
          }).responseText;

var timedata = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
```

In PHP:

```
$userdata=$_GET['userarray'];
```

is it correct?

Comment: BTW, you should reconsider using a asynchronous request instead of synchronous. Synchronous requests lock up the browser giving the user a bad experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do this instead for your javascript:

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: "http://someURL/server/test.php",
          data: { 'userarray': userarray },
          dataType:"json", 
              async: false
          }).responseText;
```

Your PHP code should be as is

Comment: data: { 'userarray': userarray }